# MySQL 5.6 default storage engine is MyISAM instead InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, centos7, systemd

I'm new here and I hope someone will help me out with **MySQL** issue.

Here I have weird situation that **InnoDB** isn't the default storage engine on:

- **MySQL** version 14.14 Distrib 5.6.39, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper.
- **linux** distribution:  CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

I have tried almost every single solution to make InnoDB as default engine but it did work for me.

Here are few things I've tried:

STEP 1

```html
files my.cnf and my.ini. has been edited in /root/my.cnf and /root/my.ini and /etc/my.cnf as:

[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_bin
default-storage-engine=INNODB
max_allowed_packet=256M
innodb_log_file_size=2GB
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
binlog_format=row
```

STEP 2
after files was saved I did restart the MySQL in few ways:

```html
Following commands DID NOT work:

# /etc/init.d/mysqld stop:  No such file or directory  
# /etc/init.d/mysql stop:  No such file or directory 
# service mysqld stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysql.service
Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit not found.

Following commands DID work:

# service mysql stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysql.service
# service mysql status (was Active: inactive (dead))
# service mysql start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysql.service
# service mysql status (was Active: active (running))
```

STEP 3

```html
 mysql> SHOW ENGINES;
    +--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
    | Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        
    | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
    +--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
    | FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 
    | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
    | MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          
    | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | MyISAM             | DEFAULT | MyISAM storage engine                                          
    | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             
    | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         
    | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    | InnoDB             | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
    | PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             
    | NO           | NO   | NO         |
    +--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
    9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql>
```

STEP 4
I have try the following command and I finally get InnoDB as DEFAULT but still didn't work cos once you reset mysqld it comes back to  MyISAM is DEFAULT

```html
SET default_storage_engine=INNODB;
```

This is really frustrating, your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: do you have any mysqld related config files in /etc/my.cnf.d/?

Comment: No there is not "my.cnf.d" in etc path, I also run sudo find / -name  my.cnf.d and nothing at all. Any more suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's case sensitive. Have you tried `InnoDB` instead of `INNODB`?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing related to case sensitive, already have tried. But thank you any way.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by doing these steps: navigate to > phpmyadmin -> Home-> variables -> storage engine and change it MyISAM to InnoDB

see the picture

[image]

Comment: it is possible but this is not an issue cos we don't need to edit existing DB. I have problem when I'm creating new DB then some softwares won't proceed with installation (in this case Atlassian Confluence) if default storage engine is not INNODB.

Comment: this way not for existing DB it's default storage engine even when you create any database or table

Comment: my apologise for this, I didn't read your answer properly. This should work as well I guess. In meantime I've reinstall MySQL and everything was ok after that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. I did "uninstalling and reinstalling completely MySQL with the same  MySQL version 5.6.39 " after that everything was great. My InnoDB has changed to default-storage-engine=INNODB.